# Stuck On Multiple Views with similar names in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good Day Everyone!

I am working on a portfolio SPA, and I am currently stuck. Is there a way to only use one view and have that view and link change dynamically? 
That is instead of having this html repeated for each view as seen in the routes, just use the HTML once and have data in that view updated on the fly?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container "ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">{{photos[0].name}}
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- /.row -->

<!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <img class="img-responsive"  ng-src="{{photos[0].url}}" alt="daltonTower" >
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Project Description</h3>
    <p>{{photos[0].description}}</p>
    <h3>Project Details</h3>
    <ul ng-controller="PortfolioEntryCtrl">
        <li>{{points[0].height}}</li>
        <li>{{points[0].floors}}</li>
        <li>{{points[0].squarefeet}}</li>

    </ul>
</div>

</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<!-- Related Projects Row -->
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h3 class="page-header">Related Projects</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#/portfolio2">
        <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" ng-src="{{photos[1].url}}" alt="50Dalton">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#/portfolio3">
        <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" ng-src="{{photos[2].url}}" alt="ChristianScienceCenter">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" ng-src="{{photos[6].url}}" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" ng-src="{{photos[4].url}}" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<hr>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
.when('/portfolio1',{
         templateUrl: "views/portfolioItem_1.html",
         controller:"PortfolioEntryCtrl"
     }).when('/portfolio2',{
         templateUrl: "views/portfolioItem_2.html",
         controller:"PortfolioEntryCtrl"
     }).when('/portfolio3',{
         templateUrl: "views/portfolioItem_3.html",
         controller:"PortfolioEntryCtrl"
     }).when('/portfolio4',{
         templateUrl: "views/portfolioItem_4.html",
         controller:"PortfolioEntryCtrl"

app.controller("mainCtrl",["$scope", "$http", function($scope,$http){
$http.get('./js/images.json').success(function(image){
    $scope.photos=image;
    console.log(image);
});

}]).controller("PortfolioEntryCtrl",["$scope", "$http",    function($scope,$http){
$http.get('./js/portfoliopoints.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.points=data;
});
```

Comment: Take a look at Angular's `ngView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think use regex pattern in [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) could solve your problem:

```
$stateProvider.state("portfolio", {
    url: "/{page: portfolio[0-9]+}",// it will match 'portfolio1' or 'portfolio2' for example
    templateUrl: function (stateParams){
        //get the id from the url path like value '2' from 'portfolio2'
        var currentPageId = stateParams.page.substring(9,stateParams.page.length);
        //dynamically return the view you want to load
        return 'views/portfolioItem_' + currentPageId + '.html';
    },
    controller: "PortfolioEntryCtrl"
});
```

Instead of repeating each possible path you just need this one to match any path starts with 'portfolio' followed by the 'id'. With the regex pattern you can do even more depends on your requirement.